# Foreach array вывести нужное

Tags: массивы, php, foreach

```
Array ( [key] => field_29 [label] => Вариант обивки [name] => materials [type] => checkbox [order_no] => 5 [instructions] => [required] => 0 [conditional_logic] => Array ( [status] => 0 [rules] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [field] => field_4 [operator] => == [value] => new ) ) [allorany] => all ) [choices] => Array ( [kozhabezh] => Кожа бежевая [kozhabel] => Кожа белая ) [value] => Array ( [0] => kozhabezh [1] => kozhabel ) )
```

Как с помощью foreach вывести значения из [choices] что бы был ключ и значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (arr['choices'] as $key => $value) {
    print $key;
    print $value;
}
```

[FOREACH](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php)